# converting c++ class to an equivalent java class

Tags: java, c++

Suppose I have a constructor in c++ as:

```
public class Machine { 
public:
 Machine(int boltCount, bool failure=false); 
};
```

How do I convert this to an equivalent class in Java?

Thanks,

Comment: it is not valid c++. params with defaults can only be last ones

Comment: Really?  Besides the obvious problem pointed out by Andrey, it is simply a class declaration and a constructor.  Java does not support default argument values, so you will have to use constructor chaining.

Comment: This is not valid C++: there are no public classes, and the parameters with default values must be rightmost. So it's not clear what it actually is that you want an equivalent for.

Comment: "public class XXX" is valid C++??  When did that happen?

Comment: @Noah:  When Sun bought MicroSoft and took over the world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like that

```
public class Machine { 
   public Machine(int boltCount) { this(boltCount, false); }
   public Machine(int boltCount, bool failure) { /*body here*/ }
};
```

Comment: Ahh! Got it.. There is a constructor explosion but I think this works.. Thanks!

Comment: i want to add that C# 4.0 has optional parameters! (trying to make java developers switch to c# :)

Comment: I mean for each c++ constructor with one default value set, this gives rise to 2x Java constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use constructor chaining, as Java does not have default values for parameters:

```
public class Machine {
    Machine(int boltCount) {
        this(boltCount, false);
    }

    Machine(int boltCount, boolean failure) {
        // constructor logic
    }
}
```